# System of symmetric differential equations about an object orbiting around the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, physics

I have an object with initial displacement $\vec{s_0}$ and initial velocity $\vec{v_0}$.

This object is accelerated as: $$\vec{a}=-\frac{v^2}{s^2}\vec{s}$$ where $v$ and $s$ are the sizes of velocity $\vec{v}$ and displacement $\vec{s}$ respectively. This comes from the formula of centrifugal acceleration. I want to find the general solution to this.

I attempted: Let
$$\vec{s}=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k};\quad\vec{v}=\dot{x}\hat{i}+\dot{y}\hat{j}+\dot{z}\hat{k};\quad\vec{a}=\ddot{x}\hat{i}+\ddot{y}\hat{j}+\ddot{z}\hat{k}$$

Differentiating with respect to the time $t$. This results in:

$$\ddot{x}=-\frac{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\;x$$
$$\ddot{y}=-\frac{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\;y$$
$$\ddot{z}=-\frac{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\;z$$

And I have no idea how to move on. Maybe I shouldn't use Cartesian..?

Comment: You get angular momentum conservation as usual, so the motion is in a plane, so after a rotation you can set $z=0$. Then consider polar coordinates.

Comment: But how do I prove the conservation of angular momentum from the differential equation? @LutzLehmann

Comment: By checking the derivative of $\vec s\times\dot{\vec s}$. You should find that it is zero, so...

Comment: Are you sure of the equation of the acceleration ?Because the exponent on $s$ should be $3$ not $2$ for the acceleration to follow the universal gravitational force law.

Comment: @LexiBelleFan : The usual gravitation law does not contain the velocity. This specific form of the equation resolves so that $s^2=|\vec s|^2$ has second derivative zero.

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved the problem. @LutzLehmann

Comment: @LutzLehmann You're right.  I withdraw my previous comment.